# Custom Parcelable object passed to core

Tags: android, marshalling, parcelable

I want to send a broadcast message with intent within extra data of my custom type which implements Parcelable.

In more details: I want to create a shortcut on the HS
However system does not accept object of my custom Command type, error message: `android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.solvek.ussdfaster.entities.Command`
This object will be passed back to my app when user clicks on the shortcut.

```
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, FormActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("command", command); // Note - commmand is my custom object
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, command.getTitle());
    Parcelable iconResource = Intent
        .ShortcutIconResource
        .fromContext(this,  R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Command class I implemented xml serialization (using XStream) and serialized Command object to String as XML and then passed to core.
Not perfect solution but it works for now.